# vb.net "invalid parameter passed to C runtime function"

Tags: .net, vb.net

I use vs2015.
I see this in Immediate Window:

> "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function. Invalid parameter
>   passed to C runtime function."

After this line

```
 Dim response = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
```

What is this problem? The program not crashing, it's just strange.

Comment: It is a C language mishap, always a very nasty one.  That nothing crashed is indeed very strange, it is not a catchable exception and should always terminate the code that suffered the heart-attack.  Well, it is not your code.  When ever anything strange happens with networking code then you want to tinker with the machine configuration.  Disable anti-malware, that sort of thing.

Comment: chk = My.Computer.Network.Ping(_STATSERVER_URL, 2000)
This line throws this message 2 times too.

Comment: virus protection is disabled, but "problem" still exists.

Comment: This is a windows error, as i read it. In principle, this issue occurs after updating windows 1809.